# Error while running bundle install: bundle is locked to a parser

Tags: bundle, bundler

I just cloned a new repo and tried to run `bundle install` but getting following error

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://abcderepos.net/api/gems/rubygems/...........
Your bundle is locked to parser (2.5.0.4), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If
you haven't changed sources, that means the author of parser (2.5.0.4) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a
different version of parser (2.5.0.4) that hasn't been removed in order to install.
```

Any idea why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 6):

Looks like parser version 2.5.0.4 was pulled from [rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/parser). I ran into the same issue today as well. You will either need to update your parser version to 2.5.0.5 or downgrade to 2.5.0.3.

UPDATE: They have documentation [here](https://github.com/whitequark/parser/issues/478#issuecomment-375930229) to support why it was removed

Answer (score 5):

The solution is `bundle update parser --patch`. (Do **not** change `Gemfile.lock` manually.)